# Highlight cells where the value is the same 3 consecutive times

Tags: excel, vba, highlight

I'm trying to highlight cells in Column H where the value is the same 3 consecutive times e.g.

1. A
2. A
3. N
4. P
5. P
6. P
7. N
8. B
9. B

The 3 P's would be highlighted red but not the 2 A's or 2B's. whether this is doable in VBA or using a formula I don't know but I've been trying to get my head around it for a while. I'm sure its probably simple and I'm just stuck in a loop

any help would be muchly appreciated

Comment: This is definitely possible with VBA.  What have you already tried?

Comment: Mainly just trying different variations of OR function and trying to get conditional formatting to do the work. Nothing in VBA as of yet

Comment: I'm not an expert of conditional formatting.  I imagine it could be done, but that isn't something that I would be able to give much assistance with.  I would look into a VBA solution, that seems like it would be simpler, though others with more knowledge of conditional formatting might not agree.  Do you have any VBA experience?

Comment: I've done a bit of VBA in the past but by no means a natural at it. Do you have a solution off the top of your head or is it a bit trickier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky with Conditional Formatting. You can select `H3` and try this formula:

```
= OR( AND(H3=H1, H3=H2), AND(H3=H2, H3=H4), AND(H3=H4, H3=H5) )
```

then change the "Applies to" to the whole range.

**Update**

```
= OR( AND(H1="P",H2="P",H3="P"), AND(H2="P",H3="P",H4="P"), AND(H3="P",H4="P",H5="P") )
```

Comment: Thanks Slai, This works really well, however Is it possible to make it only highlight it when the cell contains a P, Occasionally there are 3 N's or B's and we are just trying to focus on the P's

Comment: Ah Brilliant works perfectly - Thanks very much @Slai

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a few rows above where your data starts...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick code that I didn't test very much, but try this:

```
    Sub Find_ThreeInARow()
    Dim column1 As Range
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Range
    Dim z As Range

    Set column1 = Application.InputBox("Select Column to Evaluate", Type:=8)
    If column1.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        Do Until column1.Columns.Count = 1
            MsgBox "Please select only 1 column."
            Set column1 = Application.InputBox("Select Column to Evaluate", Type:=8)
        Loop
    End If

    If column1.Rows.Count = 65536 Then
        Set column1 = Range(column1.Cells(1), column1.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count))
    End If

    For Each x In column1
        'Exit when we reach an empty cell
        If IsEmpty(x.Value) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Set y = x.Offset(1, 0)
        Set z = x.Offset(2, 0)

        'Compare this cell to the next two in the column
        If x = y And x = z Then
            x.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            y.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            z.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next x
    End Sub
```